# bMatrix with dot variable inside juping around

Tags: equations, bordermatrix

Sorry for the bad question but I could not phrase it better.

The code is as follows and the output I want is [q_s,(dot)q_s]^T (I want it as a column not as the row transpose that works).

```
\dot{x} = \dot{\begin{bmatrix}q_s \\ \dot{q}_s \end{bmatrix}}
```

Current output looks like:
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Using a dot like that over such a large construction might not be a good solution from a readability point of view. It might be better to have a dual syntax, such that the dot can be used for simple constructions like `\dot{A}` and then use say a function name for when the argument is large or complicated.

Comment: accepted that the redefinition of `\dot` by `amsmath` is a bug in this context.  added to list.  just using `\olddot` as in the second trial in the answer by @StevenBSegletes gives the desired result without any additional packages besides `amsmath`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the OP does not provide an MWE, it took a little bit to determine that the problem arises when trying to use the OP's syntax with the `amsmath` package loaded.  The `amsmath` package redefines `\dot`, presumably for the best, but in this case not so much.

If one needs this syntax (or an alternate-equivalent `stackengine` syntax) to co-exist with `amsmath`, then one can save the original `\dot` definition *before* loading `amsmath`, which I show in the MWE as `\olddot`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\let\olddot\dot
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setstackEOL{\cr}
\begin{document}
\[
\dot{x} = \olddot{\bracketVectorstack{q_s \cr \olddot{q}_s }} 
\]
\[
\dot{x} = \olddot{\begin{bmatrix}q_s \\ \olddot{q}_s \end{bmatrix}} 
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for clarification, one could restore the original definition of `\dot` after loading `amsmath`, with a `\let\dot\olddot`. However, I chose not to do this, because I don't know the ways in which the original `\dot` definition may break the way `amsmath` does things.

Comment: I get an error which reads : ! Missing \endcsname inserted.<to be read again>\def \begin{

Comment: @QuantumDart If `amsmath` is loaded, that is where the issue originates.  See my revision.

Comment: The revision works but why do we need the olddot ?? just for clarification thanks a million

Comment: @QuantumDart Off the top of my head, I don't know how `amsmath` redefines `\dot` from its original LaTeX definition.  Presumably, they did it because it makes some typesetting constructs "better."  But, obviously, in a case like this, the revision made it worse.  The `\let\olddot\dot` saves a copy of the original definition *before* `amsmath` was loaded.  It saves it in the macro named `\olddot`, which can then be used to call on the original LaTeX definition of `\dot`.